# My use of .getValues() in Google apps is not producing the desired results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following function on my Google spreadsheet:

```
function endOfAuction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thisTab = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  var thisTabName = thisTab.getName();

  var player = thisTab.getRange("C12:L12").getValues();
  var highbid = thisTab.getRange("C13:L13").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Logger.log('Player: ' + player[0][i] + ' Bid: ' + highbid[0][i]);
  }
}
```

When I execute it and then view the Execution Transcript, I get:

```
[17-10-31 15:15:57:207 PDT] Logger.log([Player: P5 Bid: 60, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:208 PDT] Logger.log([Player: P2 Bid: 50, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:209 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:209 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:210 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:210 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:211 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:212 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:212 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:213 PDT] Logger.log([Player: - Bid: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-31 15:15:57:364 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.311 seconds total runtime]
```

The char values "Player" display OK. But the numeric values "Bid" have this garbage string , []] after the number. What is going on here? What am I doing wrong? I wish to add these numbers to other cells but that does not work, Why?

***** Added information *****

The spread sheet that I am executing this script against looks like this:

I am not allowed to post the image but it can be found at
http://xx.board18.org/images/BidSheet.png

My ultimate goal is to be able to use the values in row 12 to select cells in another sheet [tab] and then to add the values in row 13 to these cells. But "highbid[0][i]" dos not seem to contain a numeric value.

Comment: Looks as if execution transcript is adding that empty array for the possible second argument of Logger.log function. If you just see logs (cmd/ctrl + enter), you won't see it. You `highbid` array will have exactly those values that are entered in the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being showed on the execution transcription are the calls to the Google Apps Script services showing the values of the parameters.

`Logger.log()` an array having two values.

> Logger.log([Player: P5 Bid: 60, []])

On the above line,

- the first value, `Player: P5 Bid: 60`, is the result of `'Player: ' + player[0][i] + ' Bid: ' + highbid[0][i]`
- the second value, `[]` is an empty array that correspond to an optional parameter that is empty.

To view the log printed by Logger.log(), instead of looking at the Execution Transcript, click on the View menu, then on Logs or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

References

- [Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) (reference)
- [Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) (guide)
- [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) (guide)